# Trying to Unmarshal a map[Priority]string

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

I have been playing around with the Golang json package, and been running into a issue, i am simply trying to unmarshal a `map[string]string` into `map[Priority]string` the easiest way, but it seems like my UnmarshalJSON isn't even running, the following is my code, i would've like to made a playground where it could run, but i am using the OS package so:

```
import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

type Priority int

const (
    VERYLOW = Priority(iota)
    LOW
    MEDIUM
    HIGH
    VERYHIGH
)

const (
    verylow  = "verylow"
    low      = "low"
    medium   = "medium"
    high     = "high"
    veryhigh = "veryhigh"

    // ANSI color constants.
    RESET      = "\x1b[0m"
    BRIGHT     = "\x1b[1m"
    DIM        = "\x1b[2m"
    UNDERSCORE = "\x1b[4m"
    BLINK      = "\x1b[5m"
    REVERSE    = "\x1b[7m"
    HIDDEN     = "\x1b[8m"
    FGBLACK    = "\x1b[30m"
    FGRED      = "\x1b[31m"
    FGGREEN    = "\x1b[32m"
    FGYELLOW   = "\x1b[33m"
    FGBLUE     = "\x1b[34m"
    FGMAGENTA  = "\x1b[35m"
    FGCYAN     = "\x1b[36m"
    FGWHITE    = "\x1b[37m"
    BGBLACK    = "\x1b[40m"
    BGRED      = "\x1b[41m"
    BGGREEN    = "\x1b[42m"
    BGYELLOW   = "\x1b[43m"
    BGBLUE     = "\x1b[44m"
    BGMAGENTA  = "\x1b[45m"
    BGCYAN     = "\x1b[46m"
    BGWHITE    = "\x1b[47m"

    TITLE_COLOUR = BRIGHT + FGGREEN
    NUMBER_COLOR = FGGREEN

    //color constants
    BLACK         = "BLACK"
    RED           = "RED"
    GREEN         = "GREEN"
    YELLOW        = "YELLOW"
    BLUE          = "BLUE"
    MAGENTA       = "MAGENTA"
    CYAN          = "CYAN"
    WHITE         = "WHITE"
    BRIGHTBLACK   = "BRIGHTBLACK"
    BRIGHTRED     = "BRIGHTRED"
    BRIGHTGREEN   = "BRIGHTGREEN"
    BRIGHTYELLOW  = "BRIGHTYELLOW"
    BRIGHTBLUE    = "BRIGHTBLUE"
    BRIGHTMAGENTA = "BRIGHTMAGENTA"
    BRIGHTCYAN    = "BRIGHTCYAN"
    BRIGHTWHITE   = "BRIGHTWHITE"
    NOCOLOR       = ""
)

type Config struct {
    Name     string
    FGColors map[Priority]string
}

type MarshalableConfig struct {
    Name     string
    FGColors map[string]string
}

var priorityMapFromString = map[string]Priority{
    veryhigh: VERYHIGH,
    high:     HIGH,
    medium:   MEDIUM,
    low:      LOW,
    verylow:  VERYLOW,
}

var priorityToString = map[Priority]string{
    VERYHIGH: veryhigh,
    HIGH:     high,
    MEDIUM:   medium,
    VERYLOW:  verylow,
    LOW:      low,
}

func (p Priority) String() string {
    return priorityToString[p]
}

func PriorityFromString(priority string) Priority {
    if p, ok := priorityMapFromString[priority]; ok {
        return p
    }
    return MEDIUM
}

func (priority *Priority) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    var s string
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &s); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    *priority = PriorityFromString(s)
    return nil
}

func main() {
    fgColors := map[string]string{
        verylow:  RED,
        low:      BLUE,
        medium:   GREEN,
        high:     BRIGHTBLUE,
        veryhigh: BRIGHTMAGENTA,
    }

    m := MarshalableConfig{"Alice", fgColors}
    b, err := json.Marshal(m)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    file, err := os.Create("testfile.json")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    file.Write(b)

    emptyConfig := Config{}
    err = json.Unmarshal(b, &emptyConfig)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Got a error from unmarshalling: %+v \n", err)
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v \n", emptyConfig)
    var x interface{} = emptyConfig.FGColors[VERYHIGH]
    fmt.Println(x.(string))

}
```

I get the error:

```
json: cannot unmarshal number high into Go value of type main.Priority
```

So the impression i get is that it never calls my UnmarshalJSON method on the priority, and i don't know if thats the way its suppose to work anyway now that i have nested the Priority type inside of the map.

So i thouth maybe i have to do a alias type for the whole map like:

```
type FGColor map[Priority]string
```

and implement unmarshal on that instead, but that doesn't seem logical, because nested structs would be a nightmare to unmarshal  i would think.

What am i doing wrong??

Comment: I believe you need to implement `encoding.TextMarshaler/TextUnmarshaler` for JSON keys. https://github.com/golang/go/issues/12146

Comment: may you share who your json document looks like ? also JSON objects don't accept number as key only strings

Comment: @YandryPozo as pointed by @AniSkywalker, the code in question will work if `Priority` implements `TextUnmarshaler` interface, see [Working example](https://play.golang.org/p/Siy6xdsDys).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated my code, as per the comment from @AniSkywalker to the following code, using the UnmarshalText:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Priority int

const (
    VERYLOW = Priority(iota)
    LOW
    MEDIUM
    HIGH
    VERYHIGH
)

const (
    verylow  = "verylow"
    low      = "low"
    medium   = "medium"
    high     = "high"
    veryhigh = "veryhigh"

    // ANSI color constants.
    RESET      = "\x1b[0m"
    BRIGHT     = "\x1b[1m"
    DIM        = "\x1b[2m"
    UNDERSCORE = "\x1b[4m"
    BLINK      = "\x1b[5m"
    REVERSE    = "\x1b[7m"
    HIDDEN     = "\x1b[8m"
    FGBLACK    = "\x1b[30m"
    FGRED      = "\x1b[31m"
    FGGREEN    = "\x1b[32m"
    FGYELLOW   = "\x1b[33m"
    FGBLUE     = "\x1b[34m"
    FGMAGENTA  = "\x1b[35m"
    FGCYAN     = "\x1b[36m"
    FGWHITE    = "\x1b[37m"
    BGBLACK    = "\x1b[40m"
    BGRED      = "\x1b[41m"
    BGGREEN    = "\x1b[42m"
    BGYELLOW   = "\x1b[43m"
    BGBLUE     = "\x1b[44m"
    BGMAGENTA  = "\x1b[45m"
    BGCYAN     = "\x1b[46m"
    BGWHITE    = "\x1b[47m"

    TITLE_COLOUR = BRIGHT + FGGREEN
    NUMBER_COLOR = FGGREEN

    //color constants
    BLACK         = "BLACK"
    RED           = "RED"
    GREEN         = "GREEN"
    YELLOW        = "YELLOW"
    BLUE          = "BLUE"
    MAGENTA       = "MAGENTA"
    CYAN          = "CYAN"
    WHITE         = "WHITE"
    BRIGHTBLACK   = "BRIGHTBLACK"
    BRIGHTRED     = "BRIGHTRED"
    BRIGHTGREEN   = "BRIGHTGREEN"
    BRIGHTYELLOW  = "BRIGHTYELLOW"
    BRIGHTBLUE    = "BRIGHTBLUE"
    BRIGHTMAGENTA = "BRIGHTMAGENTA"
    BRIGHTCYAN    = "BRIGHTCYAN"
    BRIGHTWHITE   = "BRIGHTWHITE"
    NOCOLOR       = ""
)

type Config struct {
    Name     string
    FGColors map[Priority]string
}

type MarshalableConfig struct {
    Name     string
    FGColors map[string]string
}

var priorityMapFromString = map[string]Priority{
    veryhigh: VERYHIGH,
    high:     HIGH,
    medium:   MEDIUM,
    low:      LOW,
    verylow:  VERYLOW,
}

var priorityToString = map[Priority]string{
    VERYHIGH: veryhigh,
    HIGH:     high,
    MEDIUM:   medium,
    VERYLOW:  verylow,
    LOW:      low,
}

func (p Priority) String() string {
    return priorityToString[p]
}

func PriorityFromString(priority string) Priority {
    if p, ok := priorityMapFromString[priority]; ok {
        return p
    }
    return MEDIUM
}

func (priority *Priority) UnmarshalText(data []byte) error {
    *priority = PriorityFromString(string(data))
    return nil
}

func main() {
    fgColors := map[string]string{
        verylow:  RED,
        low:      BLUE,
        medium:   GREEN,
        high:     BRIGHTBLUE,
        veryhigh: BRIGHTMAGENTA,
    }

    m := MarshalableConfig{"Alice", fgColors}
    b, err := json.Marshal(m)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    emptyConfig := Config{}
    err = json.Unmarshal(b, &emptyConfig)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Got a error from unmarshalling: %+v \n", err)
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v \n", emptyConfig)
    var x interface{} = emptyConfig.FGColors[VERYHIGH]
    fmt.Println(x.(string))

}
```

Answer (score 1):

As `AniSkywalker` and `putu` have mentioned in the comments, you could impliment [`encoding.TextUnmarshaler`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/#TextUnmarshaler).

However I think in your case since you need to use `Priority` as a json map key, it's much easier to just use Priority as a type string.

```
type Priority string

const (
    VERYLOW = "verylow"
    LOW = "low"
    MEDIUM = "medium"
    HIGH = "high"
    VERYHIGH = "veryhigh" )
```

This way you can discard the use of the following as well.

```
const (
    verylow  = "verylow"
    low      = "low"
    medium   = "medium"
    high     = "high"
    veryhigh = "veryhigh"
)
```

Comment: it is a good suggestion, but it is a open source project i am committing to, and the code uses the priorities as ints, i totally agree that using the string as index in my example would be perfectly agreeable.